# run multiple scenario from a feature file using maven command from specific file - cucumber

Tags: maven, cucumber-jvm

i have feature file ALLTests having couple of scenarios 
Ex: TC1 , TC2 ,TC3 , TC4

I want to run only TC2 and TC4 from ALLTests through maven command , how to achive this ?

I tried "--tags @ALLTests,@TC1,@TC2" it ran all testcases from ALLTests feature file .

Answer (score 3):

**EDITED**

See [Tag Expressions](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/tag-expressions)

```
--tags '@ALLTests and not (TC2 and TC4)'
```

As far as Maven, take a look at [cucumber tags based on maven profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703426/cucumber-tags-based-on-maven-profile)

Comment: Here i want to run TC2 and TC2 from ALLTests file , Your answer may end up running all TC2 and TC4 from all file which contains such tests

Comment: You didn't mention that there were other feature files.  But I changed the answer to reflect this.

Comment: in above answer 'not' means except TC2 and TC3 run rest ? If so I'm not looking for . I'm specific about running only required tests ex : TC2 & TC4 out of TC1 to TC4

Comment: OK. You can have your money back.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#tags):
"
Tags are a great way to organise your features and scenarios.

They can be used for two purposes:

- Running a subset of scenarios
- Scoping hooks to a subset of scenarios
  "

"You can tell Cucumber to only run scenarios with a particular tag" (Source: [Running a subset of scenarios](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#running-a-subset-of-scenarios))

And you can use [tag expressions](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#tag-expressions) to specify subsets of features/scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/cucumber/tag-expressions

If you only want to run tags @TC2 and @TC4 that are in the AllTests feature file and they both also have the @AllTests tag, you can do something like this

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options= --tags "(@TC2 or @TC4) and @AllTests"
```